# Given $3$ equations with parameters $a, b, c$, evaluate $a^2+b^2+c^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> Given the equations
>
> $$\begin{align}
> x&=cy+bz \\
> y&=az+cx \\
> z&=bx+ay 
> \end {align}$$
>
> where $x,y,z$ are not all zero, evaluate $a^2+b^2+c^2$.

I don't understand the way to relate $a,b,c$ and $x,y,z$.
Can someone explain this?

Comment: Please use MathJax to display the equations.

Comment: Solve for $$x,y,z$$

Comment: Do you mean $x^2+y^2+z^2$ ? Because: If $a,b,c$ are given, you don't need $x,y,z$ to evaluate $a^2+b^2+c^2$ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can rearrange the equations as $-x+cy+bz=0$, $cx-y+az=0$, $bx+ay-z=0$, and so
$$\begin{pmatrix}-1&c&b\\c&-1&a\\b&a&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$
This has a solution with $x,y,z$ not all zero if and only if the determinant
$$\begin{vmatrix}-1&c&b\\c&-1&a\\b&a&-1\end{vmatrix}=0.$$

Comment: This det=0, is possible only for non trivial solutions for this system of equations?

Comment: Not exactly, what this is saying is that if you have a nonzero determinant for the matrix in the answer, then the only solution is that $x=0,y=0,z=0$. If the determinant is zero, then there's a solution that's non-trivial.

Comment: You are looking for $x,y,z$ which makes sense, of course. But: What has this to do with the question of the OP about $a^2+b^2+c^2$ ?

Comment: @user90369 calculating the determinant, you get $a^2+b^2+c^2=1-2abc$.

Comment: Yes, but I find the relation to $x,y,z$ somewhat opaque in your solution (but maybe that's just me that I don't understand, wether the OP askes for $x,y,z$ or for $a^2+b^2+c^2$ ).